# Fix seed of FANN random generator

Tags: c, fann

Calling `fann_seed_rand()` or not makes no difference. How can I fix that? Goal is to do the same shuffling every time to test different ANN configurations with `fann_shuffle_data()`.

Comment: Looking at the source, it's like it's using `srand` but you must enable it first with `fann_enable_seed_rand();`

Comment: `fann_seed_rand` is an internal function which is called by `fann_create_array` and `fann_create_shortcut_array`. I don't think it matters if you call it or not. What version of FANN are you using?

Comment: @BobJarvis I'm using the 2.2.0 version, I've read that it's possible in the latests versions of FANN but I can't find how.

Comment: @usr2564301 `fann_enable_seed_rand()` gives me an undefined reference, where did you find it?

Comment: Uh– with Google? It pointed me towards https://libfann.github.io/fann/docs/files/fann-h.html and the source file, where I could confirm it should work as documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fann_enable_seed_rand()` is the function I was looking for, like @usr2564301 answered.

It's available with the >= 2.3.0 FANN library